# Auto ban failed hack attempts?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm getting log notices of activity's such as users trying to access `/js/cache/'+opts.iframeSrc+'` and other suspicious looking failed Javascript and MYSQL injections.
However these seem to come from an ip addresses that changes daily. (maybe proxies or just a different connection.)

How should I deal with this? Is there a way I can add them to an ip blacklist on Apache for 24 hours, or something? The ip address is changing all the time so I don't want have a massive list of ip's that might at some point belong to potential visitors.

Comment: If these attempts are answered by 4xy or 5xy errors, then ignore them. It's not worth thinking about a solution when there is no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and set `bantime = 86400` (for 24h).

If you use iptables, you can unban an IP with:

```
iptables -D fail2ban-apache -s IP -j DROP
```

Answer (score 3):

`mod_security` is a different approach that you can use to block the access. Is a totally different approach because it will be applied from Apache but it will protect you from unknown and unexpected attacks.

You can check it at http://www.modsecurity.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can always install http://www.ossec.net/ and you will get all sorts of "anti-hacking" protection mechanisms, even on the default configuration! It temporary bans ips and you can add extra configurations n all, for multiple services.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something simple; take a look at fail2ban or sshguard.

sshguard is arguably better as it doesn't use python and the name is something of a misnomer; it does much more than just protecting ssh. - http://www.sshguard.net/